# Two experiments with two variables on one barplot

Tags: r, bar-chart

I would like to use `ggplot` for creating a barplot which shows two experiment with two variables on one figure. So the experiments should be located in different windows and two variables for each experiment should be shown as a single bar.

That's data:

```
> dput(data)
structure(c(13336000, 16722900, 8231800, 2275200, 41271100, 99067800, 
            20305100, 26360500, 55416000, 219396000, 71722610, 84034100, 
            230630600, 254380400, 52402800, 50422300, 354388700, 438443760, 
            72343800, 86587600, 462991400, 497156100, 51817210, 65168400, 
            235045400, 290932300, 41362400, 50220300, 168440600, 196797700, 
            107294900, 158465800, 362305500, 375372400, 158236400, 209906300, 
            1367158670, 1122186600, 220191000, 203333900, 978435120, 983735500, 
            373804400, 362937700, 2104276960, 2220222960, 394261700, 410656800, 
            3267607300, 3223143500, 211954000, 271134600, 1080187900, 1410693500, 
            3261120700, 1299253600, 840738200, 1226346700, 1591379300, 1829220400, 
            3239340100, 1758611700, 2003838200, 2346221200, 2425368000, 3150723500, 
            3258315400, 3184999800, 3141234200, 4124976700, 3484620300, 4132765100, 
            3280830100, 4403308600, 2233078100, 4962721300, 2923459800, 4360192600, 
            5238580300, 5647975300), .Dim = c(4L, 20L), .Dimnames = list(
              c("Mark_Mon", "Mark_Tue", "Matt_Mon", "Matt_Tue"
              ), c("1", "2", "3", "4", "6", "8", "9", "10", 
                   "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "18", "22", "24", "26", 
                   "28", "29", "30")))
```

Desired output:

[image: something like this]

I would like to visualize the existing difference between variables in each experiment so the bars should overlap.

If possible as second output I would like to see bars for each variable next to each other, not on the top and overlap.

Comment: Can you be more precise? Using your example data, should the bars be names (Mark, Matt) and the "windows" days (Mon, Tue)? Or the other way around: "windows" = names, bars within "windows" = days? What about the values 1-30 in your columns?

Comment: Sorry for not putting enough information but it was quite late. Windows should be days, names should be bars. On Y axis should be values and on x axis columns (1-30).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm doing my best in guessing what you're trying to accomplish here. If you could clarify what values mean, it could help.

You have four variables -- the large value, the small value (1-30), the day (Mon/Tue) and the person (Matt/Mark). Assuming that 1-30 are your independent variable and the large values are your response variable, you then have the day and person as additional factors. You could identify one of these to by color, and separate the other by facet. E.g.,

(I had to massage your data into long format to make it easier for me to work with, and using the data.table package. I also changed the 1-30 values to numeric instead of strings.)

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)

dat <- structure(c(13336000, 16722900, 8231800, 2275200, 41271100, 99067800, 
            20305100, 26360500, 55416000, 219396000, 71722610, 84034100, 
            230630600, 254380400, 52402800, 50422300, 354388700, 438443760, 
            72343800, 86587600, 462991400, 497156100, 51817210, 65168400, 
            235045400, 290932300, 41362400, 50220300, 168440600, 196797700, 
            107294900, 158465800, 362305500, 375372400, 158236400, 209906300, 
            1367158670, 1122186600, 220191000, 203333900, 978435120, 983735500, 
            373804400, 362937700, 2104276960, 2220222960, 394261700, 410656800, 
            3267607300, 3223143500, 211954000, 271134600, 1080187900, 1410693500, 
            3261120700, 1299253600, 840738200, 1226346700, 1591379300, 1829220400, 
            3239340100, 1758611700, 2003838200, 2346221200, 2425368000, 3150723500, 
            3258315400, 3184999800, 3141234200, 4124976700, 3484620300, 4132765100, 
            3280830100, 4403308600, 2233078100, 4962721300, 2923459800, 4360192600, 
            5238580300, 5647975300), .Dim = c(4L, 20L), .Dimnames = list(
              c("Mark_Mon", "Mark_Tue", "Matt_Mon", "Matt_Tue"
              ), c("1", "2", "3", "4", "6", "8", "9", "10", 
                   "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "18", "22", "24", "26", 
                   "28", "29", "30")))



dat <- data.table(t(dat))
dat[,n := c(1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10, 
                   12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 18, 22, 24, 26, 
                   28, 29, 30) ]

dat.mon <- dat[,c("Mark_Mon","Matt_Mon","n")]
setnames(dat.mon, c("Mark","Matt","n"))
dat.mon[,Day := "Mon"]

dat.tue <- dat[,c("Mark_Tue","Matt_Tue","n")]
setnames(dat.tue, c("Mark","Matt","n"))
dat.tue[,Day := "Tue"]

dat.all <- rbindlist(list(dat.mon, dat.tue))

dat.long <- melt(dat.all, measure.vars=c("Mark","Matt"), variable="Person")
```

Note that the data is now organized in long format, for easy plotting:

```
    n Day Person      value
1:  1 Mon   Mark   13336000
2:  2 Mon   Mark   41271100
3:  3 Mon   Mark   55416000
4:  4 Mon   Mark  230630600
5:  6 Mon   Mark  354388700
6:  8 Mon   Mark  462991400
7:  9 Mon   Mark  235045400
8: 10 Mon   Mark  168440600
9: 12 Mon   Mark  362305500
...
19: 29 Mon   Mark 3280830100
20: 30 Mon   Mark 2923459800
21:  1 Tue   Mark   16722900
22:  2 Tue   Mark   99067800
23:  3 Tue   Mark  219396000
24:  4 Tue   Mark  254380400
25:  6 Tue   Mark  438443760
26:  8 Tue   Mark  497156100
...
etc
```

Which can then either separate it so that color denotes person, or color denotes day.

```
g1 <- ggplot(data=dat.long, mapping=aes(x=n, y=value, fill=Day)) + geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge") + facet_grid(Person~.)
```

[image: g1]

```
g2 <- ggplot(data=dat.long, mapping=aes(x=n, y=value, fill=Person)) + geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge") + facet_grid(Day~.)
```

[image: g2]

Comment: Second output is the one I was looking for. Look at the comment from previous post. Is it possible to make overlapping bars for Mark/Matt ?

Comment: In that case you're essentially wanting both dodged and stacked bars in the same plot. There may be a better way of accomplishing this, but immediately I can think of a quick fix. Facet horizontally by your 1-30 n values, and use a stacked bar chart with Day as your x variable. Your X axis will alternate Mon Tue Mon Tue Mon Tue with increasing n values. Try: 

    g3 <- ggplot(data=dat.long, mapping=aes(x=Day, y=value, fill=Person)) + geom_bar(stat="identity") + facet_grid(.~n) 

which produces http://i.imgur.com/B3fTByu.png